# XSL master/ detail

Tags: xslt, asp-classic

I have a xsl code that I would like to show a nested row below each row that the user chooses.
Let's say I have a row that shows 4 columns with the main order details, I want the user to be able to click a plus or 3 dots "..." to see more details about this order.
I have all the information loaded already to the xml on the page so there is no need to go to the db again for the details.

Is this possible?
Example will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a JavaScript question. XSLT really can't do this. Also, show some decent code samples.

Comment: What is missing in this question: 1. The source XML document. 2. The wanted result. 3. The rules to be implemented that describe how to construct the result from the source. Please, edit and provide this necessary information. It seems that you don't know what the desired result should be -- if so there is no question asked at all!

Comment: I don't think you have done enough work here for yourself.  Show us a) a sample of the input XML and b) a matching example of the HTML you would like to have generated.  Although I suspect its the Javacript/HTML bit that you are also missing as well.  In which case as Tomalak says this isn't really a XSLT question at all.

Comment: definitely javascript requirement! who misguided you as XSLT? @Itay.B

Answer (score 0):

A crude example to show how its done in javascript! :) In IE click on "allow blocked contents"

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var f=0;
function tnd()
{
if(f==1)
{
var str2="The images, quotes and everything else are intended to be maintained strictly confidential. Rightclick of the mouse has been disabled, as well as alt+printscreen and copy options do not work well in major browsers. design:aravind"
document.getElementById("t_n_d").innerHTML=str2;
f=0;
return 1;
}
if(f==0)
{
var str1="to read features, terms and conditions about this design."
document.getElementById("t_n_d").innerHTML=str1;
f=1;
return 1;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id='footertext'
style="font-size: 12px;"><span onmousedown='tnd();' style='color: red; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;'>click here</span> : <span id='t_n_d'>to read features, terms and
conditions about this design.</span></span></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy the html code in "`str2`" to load tables .. pictures or etc .. 

 (ps: replace double-quotes with single-quotes in str2)

also please note that javascript is a client-side script .. it is harms performance on over usage .. this is just to give you an idea.